# How can I setup Plone 4.0.7 for Diazo?

Tags: plone, diazo

I would like to know the correct steps to setup Diazo in a Plone 4.0.7 installation.

Thanks in advance.

Alano

Answer (score 5, accepted):

plone.app.theming is not supported on Plone 4.0. You should use Plone 4.1.

Comment: Thank you. I am new in Plone. Could you send the complete instructions to update my Plone 4.0 to 4.1 including diazo support please?

Comment: @user838067 http://plone.org/upgrade

Answer (score 3):

First, upgrade to Plone 4.1.

Then you can use **plone.app.theming** if you add the KGS to your buildout:

- http://good-py.appspot.com/release/plone.app.theming/1.0b8?plone=4.1rc3

In practice, that means editing your buildout.cfg file as follows. Add plone.app.theming to your instance eggs:

```
[instance] 
eggs += plone.app.theming
```

And update the **[versions]** section as follows. Either include all the version pins:

```
# Known good set for plone.app.theming version 1.0b8
# The latest version can be found at 
# http://good-py.appspot.com/release/plone.app.theming/1.0b8?plone=4.1rc3

[versions]
AccessControl = 2.13.4
Acquisition = 2.13.7
ClientForm = 0.2.10
DateTime = 2.12.6
…
```

Or extend the good-py config:

```
[buildout]
extends = http://good-py.appspot.com/release/plone.app.theming/1.0b8?plone=4.1rc3
versions = versions
```

Then follow the plone.app.theming and diazo instructions:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming/1.0b8
- http://diazo.org

Comment: This is just not correct. The plone.app.theming KGS *is not* included in 4.1, rather the plone.app.theming KGS is intended for Plone 4.1. If you must make it work on 4.0 then you would need to add in pins for plone.app.z3cform (which is included in Plone 4.1). plone.app.theming is not supported on Plone 4.0 as I do not have the time to maintain such a complex KGS.

Comment: I am receiving this error after a "bin/instance fg": bin/instance fg
Error: error opening file /opt/Plone4/SBX/parts/instance/etc/zope.conf: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/Plone4/SBX/parts/instance/etc/zope.conf'
For help, use bin/instance -h
Could you send a complete buildout.cfg that is working for you for Plone 4 please? Thanks in advance, Alano

Comment: @Laurence Then good-py sucks! ;-) Fixed up the answer a bit.

Comment: @user838067 https://gist.github.com/1079146

Comment: @aclark Nah, it just can't perform magic ;-)

Comment: I don't expect magic, but I do expect a KGS given that good-py aims to be a KGS manager. Maybe we need a way to exclude releases that we know don't work. After all, KGS stands for "known good set" not "known merged set" :-)